# Changing depth colorscale showing the intervals instead of only the minimum and maximum in print layout

Tags: qgis, legend, bathymetry

I have made a legend with the bathymetry color scale in it

example:

[image: example]

It only shows 0 and -30 while I have made the color scale using 10 meter intervals, so 0, -10, -20, -30.

Does anyone know how to show these intervals as well in the legend?

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about what you did with qgis to generate this image?